# about the Interface design in android

Tags: android, button

I am designing a webview. Click the different button and show different content. Like this:

[image]

I want to realize that function, when I switch the four buttons in left. It can show different content in the right.
 thanks！

Comment: what did you do to accomplish this!!

Answer (score 0):

Your have your webview and button in your xml files. In youractivityname.java try the following code

```
public class yourActivityname extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private WebView yourWebView;    
    private Button button1, button2; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // assign reference of xml activity contents to your class variables
        yourWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        String url = "https:/www.google.com";
        yourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           //load default url
           loadWebContents(url);

    }
```

create a method which load your web and call this methon onclick

```
private void loadWebContents(String url){
        yourWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            }
        });

        yourWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

On click method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            loadWebContents("www.msn.com");
            break;
        case R.id.restoreBtn:
            loadWebContents("www.gmail.com");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```